# Menu is not showing in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, menu

i am new on this, i am creating an app in android studio, and i am trying to add a menu in my android app, i have added the below code but the menu is not appearing.

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    val inflater: MenuInflater = menuInflater
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
    return true
}
```

i have also add `import android.view.Menu`

i have also create the menu.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:actionLayout="@android:layout/activity_list_item"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/map" />
</menu>
```

thank you!